# Stacking content after floating divs using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap's `float-left` and `float-right` classes. My problem is with the content that comes after these floats. It doesn't recognise there is content above it. How can I get the new div to stack underneath?

```css
* {
  outline: 1px red solid;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="float-left">
  Div left
</div>
<div class="float-right">
  Div right
</div>

<div>
  New div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, if it's no reason to wrap floating elements into bootstraps grid classes `row` and `col`, you need to wrap them into bootstraps helper class `clearfix`

```css
* {
  outline: 1px red solid;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="float-left">
    Div left
  </div>
  <div class="float-right">
    Div right
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  New div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do like this?

```css
* {
  outline: 1px red solid;
  }

.newdiv{
   display:block;
}

.cols{
   width:100%;     
}

.myrow{
   display:flex;
   margin-right: 0px !important;
   margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="myrow">
  <div class="cols">
    <div class="float-left">
      Div left
    </div>
    <div class="float-right">
      Div right
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="newdiv">
  New div
</div>
```

Comment: I see that works, but it's not what I'm after as I don't want to restrict by column numbers.

Comment: how about this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like overkill. I'm just gonna wrap a div around it with `style="overflow:auto"`. Just wondered if Bootstrap had a class that I couldn't find.